# JupyterLab is Broken

Tags: conda, jupyter-lab

I just recently performed an update --all in conda.  Since then I can not start Jupyterlab; have tried to do an additional update just on Jupyterlab, no joy.  I am getting the following error and out of ideas.  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\transutils.py:13: FutureWarning: The alias `_()` will be deprecated. Use `_i18n()` instead.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, FutureWarning)
[I 2021-06-24 15:03:02.323 ServerApp] jupyter_server_mathjax | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-06-24 15:03:02.333 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-06-24 15:03:02.333 ServerApp] jupyterlab_git | extension was successfully linked.
[W 2021-06-24 15:03:02.364 ServerApp] The 'min_open_files_limit' trait of a ServerApp instance expected an int, not the NoneType None.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ncosgrov\Anaconda3\envs\atoti\Scripts\jupyter-lab.EXE\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 518, in launch_instance
    serverapp = cls.initialize_server(argv=args)
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\application.py", line 491, in initialize_server
    find_extensions=find_extensions,
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 87, in inner
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 1872, in initialize
    self.init_server_extensions()
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\serverapp.py", line 1698, in init_server_extensions
    self.extension_manager.link_all_extensions(self)
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 359, in link_all_extensions
    self.link_extension(name, serverapp)
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\extension\manager.py", line 332, in link_extension
    extension = self.extensions[name]
  File "c:\users\ncosgrov\anaconda3\envs\atoti\lib\site-packages\nbclassic\nbserver.py", line 80, in extensions
    nb = self._extensions.get("nbclassic")
AttributeError: 'ExtensionManager' object has no attribute '_extensions'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an outdated `nbclassic` version which does not work with the latest `jupyter_server`. Upgrade to 0.2.8 or newer with:

```
conda install "nbclassic>=0.2.8" -c conda-forge
```

Or if using pip:

```
pip install -U "nbclassic>=0.2.8"
```

If you do not use nbclassic you could also disable it with:

```
jupyter server extension disable nbclassic
```

There is mor information in related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/10228).

Comment: Thank you very, very much; worked like a charm.  Just for future reference any idea why a conda update -all would not have caught this?  Again thank you.

Comment: I am not sure, but it could be that you do not have conda-forge channel included. I updated the answer to explicitly add `conda-forge` channel because it seems that the `anaconda` channel and the `main` channel are lagging behind and are still on `0.2.6` (not that anoyone uses them - nbclassic has 277 786 downloads from `conda-forge`, while from `anaconda`...  12 - it's literally twelve... ;) - see https://anaconda.org/search?q=nbclassic).